# Select all student that dont have failing grade

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

im having problem with my query. i want to select all student that dont have failing grades. example

```
student ID  SECTION GRADE   SUBJECT
--------------------------------------
12345       A       1.5     ITC01
56789       A       2.0     ITC02
12345       A       5.0     ITC02
56789       B       1.5     ITC01 

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stud_id) AS student FROM grade WHERE grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3 and stud_id ='$student' AND section='$section'
```

but when I query, the student with failing grade is still added to the count of student that don't have failing grade.

i want to have an output like this

```
SECTION     NO. OF STUDENT  IN-TRACK    OUT-TRACK 
   A        2               1           1   
   B        1               1           0
```

thank you guys!

Comment: What is the name of your table? `Grade` also?

Comment: What's a failing grade?

Comment: Failing grade is either '5.00' or '0.00' = INC

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT section as SECTION, COUNT(stud_id) AS `NO. OF STUDENT`, 
SUM(if(grade IN(1,5), 1, 0)) `IN -TRACK`, SUM(if(grade < 1, 1, 0)) `OUT-TRACK` 
FROM grades 
GROUP BY stud_id, section
```

where table name, intrack and outtrack condition would be as you want.

Comment: @Mike Ahren Rances, was it helpful for you?

Comment: i edit your code in this way .. SELECT section, COUNT(stud_id) AS student, SUM(if(grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3,1,0)) 'IN-TRACK', SUM(if(grade in(0,5),1,0)) 'OUT' FROM grade GROUP BY section .. but i really want to sort those who student that have failing grade .. so if a student have failed grade. it will not count in 'IN-TRACK' but in this code     the student still being count in 'INTRACK' even though the student have failing grade.... thank you for helping i hope that you understand my question.

Comment: that is not a problem bro. but I think if the condition part of my query is added properly then his issue would be resolved\

Comment: Yes your code is almost right. My only problem now is make a query that will sort the group of subject of the student that when it has a failed grade it will not go to in-track.

Comment: what is the failed grade condition?

Comment: the condition is if one of the subject of the student have "5.00" or "0" = INC the student is "OUT-TRACK" but if the whole subject does not have any failed grade he is in "IN-TRACK" .. ex. if the 5 subject of a student are all between 1 and 3 then = 'IN-TRACK' else if one of the 5 subject have grade='5' or grade='0' then = 'OUT-TRACK'

Answer (score 0):

In your current sql statement, it will count the record in the column `grade` between the value of `1 and 3`.

You have to do it like this instead. This query will give you the number of students above or equal to `3`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stud_id) AS student FROM 'yourtablename'  
           WHERE grade >= 3
           AND stud_id ='$student' AND section='$section';
```

Comment: my code is very wrong in many way... what i really want is to separate student that have faling grade..for example if a student have 5 subjects but 1 of the subject is failed. the student will count to as "OUT-TRACK" but if the student dont have any failed in 5subject it will count to "IN-TRACK" . i hope you understand my question thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.student_id
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.student_id = x.student_id
   AND y.grade IN(0,5)
 WHERE y.student_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: i only use 1 table maam

Comment: @MikeAhrenRances So do I.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.